Stripe: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')"
i can't create a payment link for a product of stripe. Am i missing something in the code or is this something inside the API going on? Also just in case how do i check my currently installed stripe version?
NodeJS code:
async createPaymentlink(data) {
        try {
          const params = new URLSearchParams();

          params.append('line_items[0][price]', data.line_items[0].price);
          params.append('line_items[0][quantity]', data.line_items[0].quantity);
          params.append('after_completion[1][confirmation]', data.after_completion[0].confirmation);

            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },

            body: params});
            return { data: response };
            } catch (err) {
            return { error: err.message };
            }
        }

JSON body:
{
    "line_items": {
        "price": "price_1PtUNVA15zK6SDK7f0llFJ3v",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    "after_completion": {
        "type": "confirmation"

    }
}


I would be a little concerned this is Javascript you're intending to execute in the frontend, in the browser? You can't do this type of code on the frontend, it exposes your STRIPE_SECRET_KEY to anyone visiting the website.

i'm executing this code from a strAPI project in a workspace

So your code is in a backend route? :) https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/routes => https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/controllers

The createPaymentlink function code assumes that data.line_items is an array, as signified by the bracket notation (e.g. data.line_items[0]).
The JSON you've shared, which I assume is what is passed to the data parameter, does not have an array shape. Instead, you should update your code to be:
const params = new URLSearchParams();

params.append('line_items[0][price]', data.line_items.price);
params.append('line_items[0][quantity]', data.line_items.quantity);
params.append('after_completion[1][confirmation]', data.after_completion.confirmation);


oh i see, so the object access does not require to be treated like that. Thank you for the clarification. This solved my issue.

Yes, the square bracket notation is for accessing array indices. You pass the index of the item you want to read into the brackets (e.g. line_items[0] would read the first object in the line_items array).
